# Returning ether from a payable function using transfer

Tags: solidity

Is it possible to return ether sent to a smart contract payable function, by using `transfer` to return funds to the sender?

I am experimenting with a use case where a contract keeps a list of buyers who have sent a sufficient quantity of ether, and return any excess ether as 'change'. I have a contract that looks a bit like the following:

```
pragma solidity '0.4.19';

contract Purchaseable {
  uint public price;
  address[] public buyers;

  function buy() public payable {
    require(msg.value >= price);

    // Keep a list of buyers who have transferred enough ether
    buyers.push(msg.sender);

    // Give the sender some change
    uint change = msg.value - price;
    // This line blows up with VM Exception: revert
    msg.sender.transfer(change); 
  }
}
```

However, the last line `msg.sender.transfer` blows up. It's hard to debug from there. Why doesn't this work?

<s>One theory I have was that maybe it is impossible to transfer funds back to the sender as part of the same transaction. I can't find any documentation of what `transfer` actually does in reference to blocks and transactions to know if my approach is even supported. Is there a better way to part refund ether sent to a payable function?</s>

Comment: `attendees.push(msg.sender);` you haven't defined `attendees`, you should write `buyers` there.

Comment: So is it working now?

Comment: okay, no problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is `msg.sender` a contract in this case? For a contract to receive ether by `transfer` or `send`, it should have a `payable` fallback function, which does not consume more that 2300 gas.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

contract Payable {

    // The fallback function has no name and should be payable
    function() public payable {
        emit GotPaid(msg.value);
    }

    event GotPaid(uint256 value);
}
```

Comment: Yes well deduced! It was being tested from a solidity unit test contract, and I didn't have a payable fallback function. I recall running into this before but it's not at all intuitive that this is the error from the 'VM Exception revert'. Makes sense now,