# Contract reverted in ropsten - Sending ether via contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle, remix

I was trying to send ether via contract and tested in remix

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
contract Ballot {

   function sendRequestToPay( uint256 etheramount1,address receiver) payable{

                  receiver.transfer(etheramount1);
     }
 }
```

Internal transaction was successfully executed over ropsten

And I tried same function with nodejs but contract is reverted.

**JsFile**

```
Paycontract.deployed().then(function(instance){

 var registerInstance = instance;
 var amt = 1;
 var receiver = '0x...' //Address

 return registerInstance.sendRequestToPay(amt,receiver,{from: inwallet,gas: 4000000,value:web3.toWei(0.8,'ether')})
    });
```

Comment: Is the receiver a contract? If so: [see this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/47415/28303)

Comment: No here receiver is the address of other account...Is this not the way of transfering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing only 0.8 ETH using `web3.toWei(0.8,'ether')` but trying to transfer 1 ETH from the contract as the parameter passed in `amt` is 1.

If you are looking to transfer same value of ETH which is passed with the transaction you can try `receiver.transfer(msg.value);`.

The smallest unit of Ether is Wei, you can use others: http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html

Hope this will resolve the issue.

Comment: Yea..Its working now but 1Wei is transfered..not 1 ether

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: What if I'm calculating 'etheramount1' in contract and need to perform address.transfer(etheramount1)....Amount transferred will be in Wei instead of ether...I tried multiplying 'etheramount1' with '1000000000000000000' for converting to ether...But Is there another method?

Comment: yes, you can use the units, that's why i added link above. write `address.transfer(1 ether)`

Comment: But here value is in variable 'etheramount1'...I cant give address.transfer(etheramount1 ether)

Comment: Write it as `address.transfer(etheramount * 1 ether)`